# .NET Web API Project with Pythonnet Throwing errors when deploying on IIS

Tags: c#, .net, post, iis, python.net

I have written a post method in .NET that uses the Pythonnet to solve an optimization problem. It works fine on the Debug Mode in Swagger, but when deployed on the IIS shows Error.
Following is the the method being Called

```
public Dictionary<string, double> Fertilizerddt(List<double> Ncomp, List<double> Pcomp, List<double> Kcomp, List<double> Required, List<string> chemicalNames)
{

    if (!PythonEngine.IsInitialized)
    {
        Runtime.PythonDLL = @"C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python310.dll";
        PythonEngine.Initialize();
        PythonEngine.BeginAllowThreads();
        
    }
    using (Py.GIL())
    {
        dynamic sys = Py.Import("sys");
        sys.path.append("");
        string code = """
                    import numpy as np
                    from scipy.optimize import linprog

                    def optimize(chemical_names, *chemical_compositions, N_required=20,  P_required=20, K_required=20):
                        #Processing 
                        return result_dict, total_quantity
                    """;
        dynamic optimize = PyModule.FromString("testImport", code);\
    return finalResult;
    }
    
}
```

Now when I comment out the complete pythonnet part, the post method does work.
I have been trying a lot but could not find anything on this.
Please it'll be great if anyone can guide me in this regard.

Comment: https://halfblood.pro/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3 IIS runs your code under a different context, so behavior changes are expected. You might start from file permissions and Process Monitor can help, but there can be more challenges ahead.